# select query is working fine as standalone query but same query is not working inside a stored procedure

Tags: mysql

```
select * from attesting_Admin where email = 'aa@a.com'

result
---------------------------------------------------------------
2351        aa      aa      aa@a.com
2361        aa      aa      Aa@a.com
2371        aa      as      AA@a.com
2381        dsf wef wefwe   wefw    aa@A.com
2391        dsf wef wefwe   wefw    AA@A.com
```

But the same query is returning only case sensitive results when run inside a stored procedure

Server details -   MYSQL server
Collation      - unicode- ci

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`vhcpdbwebsvc`@`%`

     PROCEDURE `addAdmin`( IN `npi_id` MEDIUMTEXT, IN `createdBy` MEDIUMTEXT,IN `firstName` VARCHAR(50), IN `middleName` VARCHAR(50), IN `lastName` VARCHAR(50), IN `nameSuffix` VARCHAR(15), IN `phone` VARCHAR(12),IN `inEmail` VARCHAR(100),IN `nameMismatch` tinyint(4),IN `isDeleted` tinyint(4),OUT `providersAttestedById` INT,OUT `attestingAdminId` INT,OUT `expiry_date` TIMESTAMP,OUT `out_first_name` VARCHAR(50), OUT `out_middle_name` VARCHAR(50), OUT `out_last_name` VARCHAR(50), OUT `out_name_suffix` VARCHAR(15), OUT `out_phone` VARCHAR(12), OUT `statuscode` INT)
        BEGIN
        DECLARE count_from_attesting_admin_table INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
         BEGIN
         set statusCode = -4;
              ROLLBACK;
         END;
      Select count(1) INTO count_from_attesting_admin_table from attesting_admin where email=inEmail ;
            IF count_from_attesting_admin_table = 0 
            THEN
                 select count(1) into count_from_payer_provider from payer_provider_info where provider_email=inEmail;
                 IF count_from_payer_provider > 0
                 THEN
                     set statuscode = -5;
```

Comment: Could you share the stored procedure?

Comment: Select count(1) INTO count_from_attesting_admin_table from attesting_admin where email=inEmail ;
        IF count_from_attesting_admin_table = 0 
        THEN
             select count(1) into count_from_payer_provider from payer_provider_info where provider_email=inEmail;
    IF count_from_payer_provider > 0

Comment: Don't you think you are hard-coding the SP? By the way, where is the parameter declared? Edit the post and put the SP in it.

Comment: inEmail is the input variable..Added the code pls check